# Following the question link opens the question in Android stock browser

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

If I tap on the question, the link to the question follows & opens the question in the browser. However, this seems to be opening Android's 'stock' browser, instead of my default browser that is Chrome.

All other external links in the answer open in Chrome. I'm running the app on the Nexus 4 running a custom ROM (CM + PA hybrid called JellyBeer)

Comment: Yep, the "open question in something that's not the Stack Exchange app" just picks a browser right now, and may pick the wrong one.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the report! This is fixed and will be released in the next update.

Comment: What is the intended behavior for this now? Because all I get is a prompt asking me to choose from all of my browsers, with no option to use one as a default.

Comment: Sadly that's the intended behavior. If we allowed the default android intent picker which includes the "set as default" option, it'd also have "Stack Exchange" in the list, the app you just clicked "View In Browser" from which seemed weird to me.

Comment: Is it possible to add an in-app setting?